# How do I deal with connection strings in web.config for a web project that is hosted in Azure with a Linked Resource

Tags: azure, ado.net, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

Im having a bit of difficulties trying to understand how to handle the connection string in my web site. The web site is hosted in Azure. The Web App in Azure has a Linked Resource to a DB also in Azure. This works fine now and all is great... But what when I need to deploy my website to my production site? During development im using a dev website and a dev db in Azure. So therefore my connectionstring is also named differently for each environment. The name of the connection string is dbname_dev. This is the name of the Linked Resource so I guess this is also the name of the connection string.
So I could just add an empty connection string with that name and then use

```
connString = 
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PREFIX_myConnStringName");
```

go retrieve the connectin string and Azure will make sure to replace i during runtime.

But what happens when the site needs to be moved to the production site and db? Then the db is named differently and then the Linked Resource name is name differently. I would then get into trouble because my code above would still have the name of the Linked Resource that I used in the dev environment.

I hope I made myself clear :) I know its at bit hard to understand.. :)

Comment: I just realized that I in the Preview Portal in Azure, I can rename the connection strings. So I guess I could just make sure to name the connection string the same in my production and development web app, despite them having a different data source... But is that really the "official" way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of naming the connection string in your web.config you can set the connection string from your app's settings sections in the portal.  Those settings will stay in the same slot.

This way when you swap your dev and production slots, your prod slot will get the new bits but will keep the old (prod) connection string setting.

You can find more details here: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/11/azure-websites-slots